# .router-link-active not working in vue css

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, components

I have a Vue element which looks more or less like this

```html
<template>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <router-link to="/somewhere">Test123</router-link>
        </nav>
    </header>
</template>

<style scoped>
    nav .router-link-active {
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

But it is not making the router-link (a) coloured white. I've tried looking in chrome inspector and it doesn't show that it has the class .router-link-active. How could I fix this? Why is it happening?

Comment: Can you provide `router` config object?

Answer (score 0):

Scoped attribute makes the styles to be constrained. Styles are applied only to your component, it do not leak into children components.

Basically, scoped makes it (nomen omen) SS instead of CSS. Just StyleSheets, without Cascading.

You can either remove scoped from your style declaration or define some general top level styles for (lets say) all of active router links for the whole app.